# Initialization of multiple references Java

Tags: java, pointers, pass-by-reference

I have my linked list class as follows:

```
class ListNode {
 public int val;
 public ListNode next;
 ListNode(int x) {
     val = x;
     next = null;
 }
}
```

Now in a method which has the signature

```
public ListNode getIntersectionNode(ListNode h1, ListNode h2)
```

I have a statement like:

```
ListNode t1=h1,t2=h2;
```

This gives a compiler error, which is confusing to me because in C++, I could simply do:

```
ListNode *t1=h1,*t2=h2;
```

(With the C++ one, the method would be accepting `ListNode *h1 and ListNode* h2`).
Can anyone explain why I can't initialize multiple references in the same statement?

Update for minimal reproducible example:

```
public ListNode getIntersectionNode(ListNode h1, ListNode h2) {
    if (h1 == null || h2 == null)
        return null;
    int len1 = 0, len2 = 0;
    ListNode t1 = h1, t2 = h2;
    while (t1 != null) {
        len1++;
        t1 = t1.next;
    }
    while (t2 != null) {
        len2++;
        t2 = t2.next;
    }
    int diff;
    diff = (len1 > len2) ? len2 - len1 : len1 - len2;
    t1 = h1, t2 = h2;
    if (len1 > len2)
        while (diff--> 0) t1 = t1.next;
    else
        while (diff--> 0) t2 = t2.next;
    ListNode ans = (len1 > len2) ? t1 : t2;
    return ans;
}
```

That's the complete method.The compiler error is:

```
./Solution.java:22: error: ';' expected
        t1=h1,t2=h2;
```

Comment: Please show the compiler error, give us a [mcve]. What you show here should be (/could be) fine.

Comment: @AndyTurner I have updated now

Comment: The error is at the line below `diff=(len1>len2)?len2-len1:len1-len2;`, Replace `t1=h1,t2=h2;` by `t1=h1; t2=h2;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler error isn't on this line:

```
ListNode t1=h1,t2=h2;
```

It's on this line:

```
t1=h1,t2=h2;
```

You can declare multiple variables in a single declaration, but can't do multiple assignments in a single statement (*). Like it says: you need a `;`:

```
t1=h1; t2=h2;
```

---

(*) Ok, you *can* do multiple assignments in a single statement. For example:

```
for (;; t1 = h1, t2 = h2) { ... }
```

This is allowed because the `ForUpdate` is a list of `StatementExpression`s (assignments are SEs).

You can also do `t1 = t2 = h1;`, which first assigns the value of `h1` to `t2`, and then assigns the value of `t2` to `t1`.

What I should have said, more precisely, is that you can't use multiple statement expressions in a single statement (other than in the `ForInit` in a basic for statement) separated by a comma. The separator you have to use is `;`, making it into two statements.

Comment: We can't do multiple assignments in one statement?Where can I find this, I have googled and read documentation but I can't find that anywhere.

Comment: You won't find most things that you can't do in a language explicitly documented: there are simply too many to enumerate. You could determine it from the grammar if you really wanted.

Answer (score -2):

you can't use multiple assignment statements in a single line, if you want then separate by using a semicolon between them.
At the following line ListNode t1=h1,t2=h2;

write as below t1=h1; t2=h2;

Comment: As you can see in the accepted answer, you can't do multiple assignments in a single line. But you can declare several variables and assign values to them. So ListNode t1=h1,t2=h2; is totally fine